# how to show auth0 client loginasync in webview

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, auth0

I am trying to build an app with login page that uses auth0, now when I call LoginAsync the sdk will popup the login page in a different frame, I want to show the login page in a webview that is defined in xaml.

I want to show login page that popup in this [[image: enter image description here] picture [1]] in a webview defined in this is xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Auth0App.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Auth0App"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Margin="10,0">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Style="{ThemeResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}">Log in using widget</TextBlock>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10">
                <Button Content="Login" x:Name="LoginButton" Click="LoginButton_OnClick"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <WebView Name="loginWebView"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

and the code behind is:

```
using Auth0.SDK;
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;


namespace Auth0App
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private Auth0Client auth0Client;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            auth0Client = new Auth0Client("mydomain", "**************************");
        }

        private async void LoginButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var user = await auth0Client.LoginAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

How would I wire auth0 client with my webview?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at [the Auth0 quickstart](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/wpf-winforms) for this kind of project. I think you're about halfway there, and the quickstart would get you the rest of the way.

Feel free to reach out if there's anything missing or you need further assistance!

--Kassandra Perch, Developer Evangelist

Comment: The nugget package "Auth0WinformsOrWPF" can't be installed for "Blank App(Window 8.1)". Also "WindowWrapper" namespace can't be found in this type of project.